# If merging is represented by a DAG in git, why is the git log linear?

Tags: git, directed-acyclic-graphs

[image]
[image]

As the above two diagrams suggest there are two git branches `A` and `B` with common ancestor `c1`. As the second diagram suggests I try to merge branch `B` into branch `A`. Assume there was a conflict while merging which I resolved and finally made the commit `C5`.

My doubt is where does this DAG scenario come in from ? Does git use this DAG structure internally for merging purposes ? I am confused because if after the merge I do git log, the log as expected is linear, but merge history isn't. Am I missing something ?

Sorry if I mixed up something, I am new to git.

Comment: `git log` is linear because it's presented as a *list*. Merge commits will have two (or more) parents. If you want to see things as a graph, use a graphical tool, or try `git log --graph`. Git's commits do form a graph, not "internally for merging purposes" but because that's how Git works. There's noting "internal" about it. It's currently very unclear where your confusion lies.

Comment: @meagar thanks. git log --graph cleared all my doubts :D